# Why is Flowplayer not working on Android or IE8? Video is in mp4 format

Tags: android, wordpress, internet-explorer, browser, flowplayer

Using the latest version of Flowplayer and it is working on everything but Android and IE8. In IE9 it's showing "HTML5: video not found" which is obviously not true since it's playing on other browsers.

The videos are in mp4 format. Does Android and IE not support this?

Why does flowplayer not revert back to flash?

My embed code looks like this:

```
    `<div id="postFeaturedImage">
    <div class="flowplayer" data-rtmp="rtmp://s3rsj73dgt28vf.cloudfront.net/cfx/st">
    <video id="video" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/chardonnay/<?php echo get_post_meta($post -> ID, 'video-low-resolution', true); ?>.mp4" poster="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>"></video>
    </div><!-- flowplayer -->
</div><!-- postFeaturedImage -->`
```

Answer (score 0):

Android, as a whole, only supported mpeg 4 encoded baseline profile with the MOOV atom set correctly. Newer devices support other methods (HLS & higher profiled mpeg4 types) but not universal.

Here is more definitive info : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations